# Logging path from YAML

Tags: java, spring, yaml, logback, slf4j

I am trying to get my logging path from YAML file, I have tried few but none of them worked perfectly, one of my recent approaches is as

In Yaml file I have added

```
logging:
    path: /home/Properties/logs
```

In my logback.xml file

```
<file>${LOG_PATH:-logs}/logfile.log</file>
```

by using the above codes in YAML and XML file my logs are getting created in inside my directory where my codes are placed say my codes are in E:/code/Project directory and the logs are getting created inside the Project directory but I want my logs to be created in E:/home/Properties/logs

Comment: Hope this will be useful: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/logging-file.html

Comment: @dkd The link is a guide for application.properties and I needed support for application.yml

Comment: okay, add following in application.yml and check `logging:file:/home/Properties/logs/logfile.log` and remove property `logging:
    path: /home/Properties/logs`, if this does not work try with deleting `logback.xml` file with above property changes

Comment: @dkb thanks but I already tried these two options but none worked as expected